# Guy-Charles Cros quoted by Osamu Dazai: "comme un crapaud contourne une pierre"

Tags: french-language, quote-source, guy-charles-cros

In *No Longer Human* Osamu Dazai attributes the quote below to Guy-Charles Cros:

> …et puis on recommence encore le lendemain
> avec seulement la même règle que la veille
> et qui est d'éviter les grandes joies barbares
> de même que les grandes douleurs
> comme un crapaud contourne une pierre sur son chemin…

I could not find a source of this quote and would greatly appreciate if someone could give me directions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is from [*Les fêtes quotidiennes*](https://archive.org/details/lesftesquotidi00cros/page/n3/mode/2up) (1912):

> Il en est pour qui la vie est chose simple,
> chose facile et de tous les jours;
> on fait sa correspondance, on « fait l’amour »,
> on fait, avant tout, « ses affaires »
> et puis on recommence encore le lendemain
> avec seulement la même règle que la veille
> et qui est d’éviter les grandes joies barbares
> de même que les grandes douleurs
> comme un crapaud contourne une pierre sur son chemin.
>
> There are those for whom life is a simple thing,
> an easy thing, an everyday thing:
> you write your letters, you “make love”,
> you do, first of all, “your business”,
> and then you start again tomorrow
> with just the same rule as yesterday,
> which is to avoid great savage joys
> as well as great sorrows
> like a toad avoids a pebble in its path.
>
> <sub>Guy-Charles Cros (1912). [*Les fêtes quotidiennes*, pp. 9–10](https://archive.org/details/lesftesquotidi00cros/page/8/mode/2up). Paris: Mercure. My translation.</sub>

I found this by searching the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/) for a short distinctive phrase from the poem (I picked “grandes joies barbares”), and selecting the “Search text contents” option. This resulted in [four hits](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%22grandes%20joies%20barbares%22&sin=TXT): the original publication of *Les fêtes quotidiennes* and three quotations via Osamu Dazai. (If there had been many hits I would have sorted by publication date and look at the earliest appearances, but that wasn’t necessary in this case. If the Internet Archive did not have any relevant hits I would have tried [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/advancedSearch/) and discovered an earlier publication, in [*Mercure de France*, 16 juin 1911, p. 715](https://www.retronews.fr/journal/mercure-de-france/16-juin-1911/118/4093251/43).)

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask, did you just happen to know this or do you have a more involved routine for looking up quotes? For me just using common search engines did not prove successful at all here.

Comment: I would recommend "pierre" for stone, as "pebble" is closer to "caillou" or "galet", which suggests more a smooth and round stone, possibly smaller, too. Unrelated, the colon after "an everyday thing" should be a semi-colon.

Comment: I'll have to disagree. I'm not sure how colon is better in this case, but I'm sure it has a different meaning. As for pebble, the kind of pebble a toad would encounter on its path, short of taking a stroll on a beach are "cailloux", which are typically too small for a toad to need to go around them.

Comment: @njk2: I used some freedom in making the translation: it's not meant to be literal. I picked "pebble" for its sound, and chose colon over semi-colon as I interpret the second part of the sentence as being an explanation or expansion of the first part.